# jQuery droppable destroy in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a drag and drop grid and I'm trying to remove the droppable when I move the mouse out of that particular row on the grid. This works totally fine in Chrome! In IE11 it throws an exception as follows:

> JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on droppable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Here's my code:

```
row.mouseleave(function () {
    $(".labelCell:not(.ui-draggable-dragging)", row).each(function (index, value) {

        $this = $(value);
        $this.droppable("destroy");
    });
});
```

The exception is being thrown on this line: `$this.droppable("destroy");`

The question is how can I "destroy" the droppable without getting this exception?

Comment: Have you setup your droppables by this point (i.e. `$(element).droppable();`)? It appears by the error, that you're trying to destroy a control that has not yet been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing for it to be droppable before the destory call:

```
if ($this.hasClass('ui-droppable')) {
    $this.droppable("destroy");
}
```